# SQL Append query

Tags: sql

Please help, I'm having two tables Table_A and Table_B below, I would like to append data from Table_B to Table_A where Table_A.C1 = Table_B.C1.  The Table_A final result below.

```
Table_A 
C1      | C2      
-------- ---------
1@a.com | e@a.com 


Table_B 
C1      | C2      
-------- ---------
1@a.com | abc@.com 

**FINAL RESULT**

Table_A 
C1      | C2      
-------- ---------
1@a.com | e@a.com; abc@.com
```

Comment: Have you done anything at all to solve this problem?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Also, what if c2 column's data is same in both the tables. do you still want append or just when it's different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update ta
set ta.c2 = ta.c2 + ';' + tb.c2
from Table_A ta
inner join Table_B tb on tb.C1 = ta.c1
```

Comment: That's non-standard SQL

Comment: did he ask for ANSI compliant? Table_A is a Microsoft default, i can also tell by his copied output.  it worked for him it seems....chilllllll out

Comment: The  `sql` tag refers to standard SQL. You should at least have stated for which DBMS this is

Comment: @jp2631 next time tag  TSQL or the neo community will eat you alive

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would recommend is good database normalization, which may make the problem you are trying to solve moot. See [Database Normalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3282510/database-normalization)

If your database is as normalized as possible, a better idea than what you have would be to leave Table A alone and create a view with rows made up of "matches" between Table A and Table B. It is very bad database form to have multiple values in a column.

Use: CREATE VIEW table_A_table_B AS SELECT * FROM Table_A JOIN Table_B ON Table_B.C1 = Table_A.C1.

The advantage of a view is that the view "table" will update every time either Table_A or Table_B is updated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ANSI `MERGE`:

```
MERGE table_a a
USING table_b b
ON a.c1 = b.c1
WHEN matched THEN
UPDATE SET a.c2 = a.c2 || ';' || b.c2;
```