# sql get description 2 column on 1 table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables:

**car**

```
ID    Desc
1     BMW
2     Audi
```

**user**

```
ID   Name    ID_car1     ID_car2
1    Jack       1           2
```

**Data View**

```
ID    Name   ID_car1   Desc_car1    ID_car2    Desc_car2
1     Jack      1          BMW        2           Audi
```

How to query to show `desc_car1` and `desc_car2` on Data view?

Comment: you need to nomrmalize your database. here is a link for that. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3282510/database-normalization

Comment: sorry data view only for report on php table, how to get this data?

Comment: I don't see any relationship between the users and the cars.  Is there a third table somewhere which stores this information?

Comment: sorry, i already edited the data

Answer (score 1):

Ideally there should be a third *junction* table which persists the relationship between users and cars.  If you want a literal query to generate the above output in the absence of such a table, then we would have to use a cross join between `car` and `user`, because no other relations exist:

```
SELECT
    u.ID,
    u.Name,
    MAX(CASE WHEN c.ID = 1 THEN c.ID END) AS ID_car1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN c.ID = 1 THEN c.`Desc` END) AS Desc_car1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN c.ID = 2 THEN c.ID END) AS ID_car2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN c.ID = 2 THEN c.`Desc` END) AS Desc_car2
FROM car c
CROSS JOIN user u
GROUP BY
    u.ID,
    u.Name;
```

[image]

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

Using your recent information, we can get the Data View using a query, like so:

```
select u.ID, u.Name,
  u.ID_car1, c1.Desc Desc_car1,
  u.ID_car2, c2.Desc Desc_car2
from user u
  join car c1 on u.ID_car1=c1.ID
  join car c2 on u.ID_car2=c2.ID;
```